# Set Specified Views background stylistically and changing by themes

Tags: android, themes, android-theme, android-styles

I look for google and keeping fighting on searching keyword, but still nothing.

What I want just like:

```
  <style name="Theme.DefaultWhite" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="MyCustomBackground">#33ffffff</item>
  </style>
  <style name="Theme.DefaultBlue" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="MyCustomBackground">#3388ffff</item>
  </style>
```

and set the item at my **specified** (other of it use Android default) Views.

```
    <ImageView>
       id = "@+id/NNI_ivCards"
       background="@style/MyCustomBackground"
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView>
       id = "@+id/NNI_ivBarRoot"
    </ImageView>
```

**NNI_ivCards** `ImageView` must be changed the background color by themes, and **NNI_ivBarRoot** will not changed by themes.

I need stylistically custom resource which it values changed according to theme.

If it Android designed not to put extra custom values in styles,I need Java code as short as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so,

this code could change the color (any color) by changing theme.

first, you have to add 2 Style to your `style.xml` like this:

```
<style name="DefaultTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.DefaultTheme" >

</style>
```

here just i add **DefaultTheme** and **CustomTheme**, now go to your `manifest.xml` and add this line `android:theme="@style/DefaultTheme"` to your *application* tag :

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/DefaultTheme"
        ...>
```

create new xml file named `attrs.xml` and add this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="color1" format="color" />
    <attr name="color2" format="color" />
</resources>
```

go back to style and add these colors :

```
<style name="DefaultTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="color1">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="color2">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.DefaultTheme" >
    <item name="color1">#33ffffff</item>
    <item name="color2">#3388ffff</item>
</style>
```

now you have 2 theme, in **DefaultTheme** color1 and color2 is #FFFFFF, and in **CustomTheme** color1 is #33ffffff and color2 is #3388ffff

go to your imageView and add this color :

```
<ImageView>
    android:id = "@+id/NNI_ivCards"
    android:background="?attr/color1"
</ImageView>
```

to change the theme you must call `setTheme(R.style.DefaultTheme);` before `setContentView()` method in `onCreate()` method, so your activity should be like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    ....
}
```

Comment: I cant change it style with theme if I hardcode it Views style.

Comment: so you need code to change theme, and the colors changing with theme. see my answer again to solve it.

Comment: You Are My Hero! Set ?attr/color1 does it !!!!!! And that attr maybe needs to under <declare-styleable> ?

Comment: yes just use ?attr/color1 , and also you can add many colors like that way, but look again to line `<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.DefaultTheme" >` it was wrong.